# Where(i => i % 2 == 0)

Tags: c#

I'm currently learning about PLINQ (Parallel Language Integrated Query) on Visual Studio 2012's C#.

In the one lesson `Where(i => i % 2 == 0)` was given to me, but I've no idea what it means and the book i'm studying from didn't give any explanation.

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Well which *part* of it do you not understand? The `Where` method? The lambda expression syntax? The `i % 2 == 0` part?

Answer (score 2):

First hope you know `%` which is *"The % operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second"*. Read more about [% Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

if you have a list of numbers

```
var list = new List<Int32>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

var result = list.Where(i => i%2 == 0);
```

So the result will have 2,4,6,8 and 10.

Same thing can be written as

```
  var ans = new List<Int32>();

    foreach (var an in list)
    {
        if (an%2 == 0)
            ans.Add(an);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The query is selecting only even numbers, where division by 2 has no remainder.

> The `%` operator computes the remainder after dividing its first
>   operand by its second. All numeric types have predefined remainder
>   operators.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Where(i => i % 2 == 0)`
it means `i` goes to where `i % 2 == 0` that is if 
you are doing it for a list of integer it will return all even numbers from list

Answer (score 0):

lambda expressions are a bit weird at 1st however when you experiment a bit in VS (and its intellisense) you'll get used to it in no time. as soon as you type in "i=>" you declare a range variable of your type of object which implements `IEnumerable(<T>)` interface. In this case i is one element of your list (or other IEnumerable>> list, dictionary....) to investigate this case you search for even numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is the case:

```
List<int> source = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var evenNumbers = source.Where(i => i % 2 == 0);
```

`Where` is filtering `source` and returning only it's even numbers.

`Where` is a Linq extension method that works on any object implementing the `IEnumerable` interface (like`List`).

`i => i % 2 == 0` is a lambda expression. In this case it means that for each item `i` in `source`, `Where` will apply the expression `i % 2 == 0`.

`Where` selects the items in `source` for which the lambda expression is true. In this case, the expression is true when `i` is an even number.

This is because of the modulo operator `%`, which returns the remainder of the integer division between two numbers `a` and `b`: `a % b`. If `a = 4` and `b = 3`, then `a % b` values 1, because it is what remains when dividing 4 by 3. If `%` returns `0`, then it means that `a` is divided by `b`. If `b` is `2`, then it means that `a` is even.